# Write regex on Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
Zoom   src/main/java/com/directv/acm/utils  80,9%
Zoom   src/main/java/com/directv/acm/restclient/impl    81,0%
```

Hi guys, I'm trying to remove everything except numbers in my document. It's a ton of lines like this. Can anyone please write a regex for me in order to just keep the number only? Please.I hope that the result after modifying look like this (delete everything except the numbers):

```
80.9
81.0
```

My great thank to you!

Comment: You need to try something yourself... SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I only do this because it's urgent, wish that you could help. I sincerely appologize for this question @npinti

Comment: are numbers always in last?

Comment: yes @rock321987 :) I got my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> for replace then `^.*(?=\d{2},)` on the search field. Enable the `Regular expression` checkbox on the `Search Mode` and press the <kbd>Replace All</kbd> button

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Replace dialog
- In Find what, enter: [a-zA-Z /\%]*
- In Replace with, enter: \n or leave it blank
- Check: Regular expression option at the end
- Click <kbd>replace all</kbd>